# What is the difference between getiterator() and iter() wrt to lxml

Tags: python, lxml

As the question says, what would be the difference between:

`x.getiterator()` and `x.iter()`, where `x` is an ElementTree or an Element? Cause it seems to work for both, I have tried it.

If I am wrong somewhere, correct me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getiterator` is the `ElementTree` standard spelling for this method; `iter` is an equivalent `lxml`-only method that will stop your code from working in `ElementTree` if you need it, and appears to have no redeeming qualities whatsoever except saving you from typing 7 more characters for the method name;-).

Comment: I'd be interested to see your response to my answer ;-)

Comment: @Bruce, good point -- I hadn't considered 2.7 (not yet released at that time, I believe).

Comment: Ah, I overlooked the fact that your answer was from June ;-)

Comment: This is not valid anymore, see @BrucevanderKooij's answer.

Answer (score 8):

The [Python documentation for ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.getiterator) states that the `getiterator()` method has been deprecated starting with version 2.7 and says to use `Element.iter()`. The [lxml API documentation](http://codespeak.net/lxml/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#getiterator) states the same but also mentions that the implementation of `getiterator()` in lxml diverges from the original ElementTree behavior.

Interestingly enough the documentation also states that "If you want an efficient iterator, use the tree.iter() method instead". Note the word "efficient", which leads me to believe there is most certainly a difference in implementation between `getiterator()` and `iter()`, but without checking out the source I can't be 100% sure.

Anyhow, if something has been deprecated it's clear they don't want you to use it.